# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/amqp/3.1/mule-amqp.xsd'

Tags: eclipse, mule, amqp

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <mule xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
  xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
  xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file"
  xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:jms="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms"
  xmlns:test="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/test" 
  xmlns:script="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting"
  xmlns:amqp="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/amqp"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms/current/mule-jms.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file       http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/3.1/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file   http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/3.1/mule-file.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms/3.2/mule-jms.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/test http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/test/3.1/mule-test.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/3.1/mule-scripting.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/amqp http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/amqp/3.1/mule-amqp.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd" >
    <amqp:connector name="jcab" connectionFactory-ref="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory" host="localhost" port="5672"  username="admin" password="admin" specification="1.1" doc:name="Active MQ"> <service-overrides sessionHandler="org.mule.session.NullSessionHandler"/>   </amqp:connector></mule>
```

[image]
Please help me I'm really stuck in this problem from two days..I tried many examples. help will be appriciable. Thank You.

Comment: Have you checked the schema availability in the given location?

Comment: Yes I have checked it is available.. thank you for response..

Comment: Which mule version are you using? Why aren't you using ```http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/amqp/current/mule-amqp.xsd```?

Comment: I have shown picture of mule versions, and url you provided is not available.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the dependency for amqp transport from your project's classpath.

**Maven Support**

Add the following repository:

```
<repository>
  <id>muleforge-repo</id>
  <name>MuleForge Repository</name>
  <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
  <layout>default</layout>
</repository>
```

To add the Mule AMQP transport to a Maven project add the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
  <artifactId>mule-transport-amqp</artifactId>
  <version>x.y.z</version>
</dependency>
```

https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-transport-amqp 
https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-transport-amqp/blob/master/GUIDE.md

-Shanky G.